# How to get unmanaged pointer on an C# object?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I know how to create unmanaged pointer on struct.
But i want to have a unmanaged pointer that will point on an object.

I already know that i need to protect the object from the GC using

```
GCHandle.Alloc(...);
```

But i can't find a way to define a pointer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pin an instance like this:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(oldList, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Assuming it works, you can then take the address of the pinned object as a type-agnostic pointer, like this:

```
IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Don't forget to explicitly release the handle before you lose track of it (otherwise the object will remain perpetually pinned):

```
handle.Free();
```

---

Notice that I said "assuming it works" — not all objects can be pinned and those that can't will throw an exception when you attempt to pin them.

If you'd like to risk taking the address of a non-pinned object, you can use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` to attempt something like this:

```
static unsafe void* VeryUnsafeGetAddress(this object obj)
{
    return *(void**)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref obj);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `GCHandle.Alloc` with the second parameter `GCHandleType.Pinned`. Also method `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject` might be helpful.

Try these two links:

- [GCHandle.Alloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested in `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. I also suggest reading this [blog](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) post.